Strange movie with a farm boy dealing with uncertainty about his sexuality
I keep remembering bits of this movie I saw parts of ~15 years ago, but I can't put together the right keywords to find it. Here are some details:

The story centers around a boy in a farm town (I think) surrounded by
wheat fields
The boy may be metaphorically dealing with uncertainty about his sexuality (homosexuality?) though this is presented through symbolism in the movie
Crucially and I think most iconically, the boy's father keeps trying to emerge from the inside of or behind his couch, and I think the father is dead (his hands may look somewhat grey/green or decomposed?)
The boy may feel like his father disapproves of his potential homosexuality?
There's a very eerie, sparse soundtrack. I'm reminded of wind chimes...
It was in English, it was probably an American movie, and I'm guessing a release date of the mid to late 90s.
A friend suggested The Reflecting Skin (1990) but it doesn't seem to be the right movie

Does any of this ring a bell? I would highly appreciate any ideas.

The symbolic The Nature of Nicholas from 2002 about a boy coming to terms with his homosexuality.

The Nature of Nicholas is a surreal fable that follows twelve-year-old Nicholas as he struggles with an intense attraction to his best friend, Bobby. [...] All this leaves young Nicholas very confused. When images of Nicholas's absent father start to appear to him, the boy is understandably frightened. 

Nicholas lives in a farm and the movie uses horror elements to mirror his inner struggle. His father's living corpse keeps appearing to him, IIRC in his closet, under the bed and in a sofa. Here's a clip:



